# Java8 Why is my solution faster than the neat solution? (hackerrank Chocolate Feast)

Tags: java

Edit: Simplified my solution.
Edit: Removed opinion based secondary question.

Background: Atarted learning java a week or two ago using hackerranks problems as exercises and stackoverflow search + google as my teacher, I've had some limited experience learning other languages.

I did the exercise my own "noobish learner way" which I can't help but feel is a "botched job" when I see "neat & short" solutions.

However, when submitting both solutions one after another a couple of times I found the "neat" solution was quite a bit slower.

I vaguely remember something about % operations being costly, is mine faster because of no % operations or is there more to it than just that?

Exercise: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/chocolate-feast

Neat solution from discussion:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    static int cc; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t,n,c,m,r;
            t = in.nextInt();
            while(t-->0){
             n = in.nextInt();
            c = in.nextInt();
             m = in.nextInt();
                r=n/c;
                cc=r;

                    while(r>=m){
                        cc=cc+r/m;
                        r=r%m+r/m;
                    }

                System.out.println(cc); 
            }

    }
}
```

My Solution:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());    //t = number of test cases
        int[][] tc = readInput(sc, t);              //tc[t][0] = money. tc[t][1] = price. tc[t][2] = wrappers per free bar

        for (int i = 0; i<t; i++){                  //loop for all test cases
            int choc = calcChoc(tc,i);              //work out how much choc can be bought
            System.out.println(choc);               //print result for the test case
        }
    }
    //calculate how much choc he can buy with m $ at p price with w wrappers needed for a free bar
    public static int calcChoc(int[][] tc,int i){

        int m = tc[i][0];       //money he has
        int p = tc[i][1];       //price of choc
        int w = tc[i][2];       //wrappers per free bar

        int bars = m/p;         //how many bars he can buy initially
        int wrappers = bars;    //each bar is a wrapper from initial purpose

        //loop to turn in all wrappers while it is possible to do so
        while (w<=wrappers){

            int barsFromTurnIn = wrappers/w;                //bars from turning in current wrappers.
            bars = bars + barsFromTurnIn;                   //new bar count
            wrappers = wrappers - (barsFromTurnIn * (w-1)); //wrapper count reduced by amount of wrappers turned in -1 wrapper per bar recieved from turn in.

            if (w==1){ //break out of infinite loop when you get 1 bar for 1 wrapper!
                System.out.print("Infinite Bars, exiting infinite loop at bars = ");
                break;
            }
        }
        return bars;
    }
    //read input for each test case and make 2d array of the info
    public static int[][] readInput(Scanner sc, int t){

        int[][] input = new int[t][3];

        for (int i = 0; i<t; i++){
            String[] inputLine = sc.nextLine().split(" ");

            input[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[0]);
            input[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[1]);
            input[i][2] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[2]);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: The formatting of the "neat solution" is quite disgusting. Doesn't look like the work of a coding pro.

Comment: I don't like the formatting either, I guess I should have called it 'short and simple' solution instead.

Comment: I think "neat" is pretty subjective; I don't see the "neat"-ness of that code. This might also be better on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Short? Yes. Simple? No. It's virtually unreadable: badly formatted, bad variable names (single letter variables were acceptable back in the 1960s, when programs were stored on Hollerith cards. Do not do that.) There is also not a single comment to explain what is going on in the code. So no, you should not strive to code like that, quite the contrary.

Comment: Let's be fair, algorithmically it's a very elegant solution, it has all the hallmarks of a Hackerrank junkie's output. It can be turned into really good code just by reformatting and variable renaming.

Comment: In your code, this expression `(int)(Math.floor(wrappers/w));`, given `wrappers` and `w` are `int`s, is the exact equivalent of this: `wrappers/w`.

Comment: You may be learning the wrong priorities.  Your goal should -never- be to come up with "clever solutions" which, over time, can possibly end up causing performance problems as the language platform evolves.  Your goal should be to write code which is -correct- first, while relying on standard and accepted conventions.  Once your code is correct, then (and only then) should you ever concern yourself with making it fast (and only if it -needs- to be faster).

Comment: The first solution given isn't "clever", it's just what the task asked for. To even begin calling itself "clever" it should, as already noted, avoid both the modulo and division operations on two `int` variables.

Comment: How did you measure the code's performance? Based on the time score upon submission? I'm pretty sure it's a single-run score, and that is not a way to benchmark code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Quite right.  Had already deleted the comment.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well i submitted both a couple of times with significant and almost identical differences, I agree that it is not necessarily conclusive, I should probably look into the correct way of doing this kind of comparison, but I was just curious about apparent results.

Comment: As opposed to the first solution, which takes like 5 minutes to fully understand, I'm having a hard time understanding what goes on in your solution, and what performance I could expect from it.

Comment: Sorry marko, it was just written with the idea of getting the task done and never being seen by anyone. I am a total noob at this.

Comment: In any case, to answer the question as asked: yes, you should practice to be able to come up with solutions like your first example. Simplicity and elegance are highly valued.

Comment: I'd guess that You solution is faster due to sc.nextLine().split(" "); followed by the four Integer.parseInt being faster than the series of in.nextInt() but that's a wild guess based on some experience with "hackerrank" type websites where very usualy the most performance gain can be made by improving data input performance.

*EDIT*
A quick glance at java.util.Scanner source code shows me that it uses regexp matching to get the nextInt which makes my reasoning very plausible.

Comment: @Venc That's the kind of stuff I want to know :D (not because I am hell bent on squeezing performance out before I can code, but because when things occur which I find confusing I want to know WHY!)
Also made my spider web code a little bit simpler.

Comment: @Venc You're quite probably right... better coding sites serve you parsed input and exercise your code with values which demand a lot of CPU cycles. And do proper benchmarking on it, which takes _a lot_ of care.

Comment: I don't think the times there are very consistent. I ran each of the above twice, and while yours code in generally faster with little difference (0.01s max) the other differs as much as 0.03s; possibly input performance is the random variable on the site as @Venc suggest. So just by doing more of it the other code takes frequent hits.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, completely off-topic, what would you say is a better coding site?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, I too would like to know the answer to Linus' question, though my main aim is just a selection of problems to solve while learning and a discussion place where I can understand how to think about the problem better. I always bumble my way through problems with the aid of internet resources, it takes more time but I learn a lot more interesting things on the way, which are often totally irrelevant to an efficient solution but may be useful to know some time :) I just like the discussion type thing so I know how I should have done it afterwards :)

Comment: A good site that I had contact with is Codility. But its focus is job candidate screening.

Comment: A long discussion has developed in the comments. I would say your question is problematic. The first question "Why is code B faster than code A, that seems to be simpler, when it is uploaded to Hackerrank?" is answerable, and I think @Venc should post a proper answer based on his comment. But the second question, "Should I focus on trying to get neat solutions?" Is inappropriate for StackOverflow, being opinion-based and open-ended. I suggest you (OP) edit that part of the question out.

Comment: edited as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that You solution is faster due to your method of reading input data:

```
public static int[][] readInput(Scanner sc, int t){

    int[][] input = new int[t][3];

    for (int i = 0; i<t; i++){
        String[] inputLine = sc.nextLine().split(" ");

        input[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[0]);
        input[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[1]);
        input[i][2] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[2]);
    }
    return input;
}
```

being faster than the series of in.nextInt() in the "neat" solution:

```
   n = in.nextInt();
   c = in.nextInt();
   m = in.nextInt();
```

If we look at the source code of java.util.Scanner we see that it uses regexp matching for finding the nextInt in the supplied input stream and regexp matches are quite a bit slower then spliting a line on "space" characters and parsing 3 integers:

```
public int nextInt(int radix) {
    // Check cached result
    if ((typeCache != null) && (typeCache instanceof Integer)
        && this.radix == radix) {
        int val = ((Integer)typeCache).intValue();
        useTypeCache();
        return val;
    }
    setRadix(radix);
    clearCaches();
    // Search for next int
    try {
        String s = next(integerPattern());
        if (matcher.group(SIMPLE_GROUP_INDEX) == null)
             s = processIntegerToken(s);
        return Integer.parseInt(s, radix);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        position = matcher.start(); // don't skip bad token
        throw new InputMismatchException(nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```